# Declaring type based on variable

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, I can do something like this to have a variable implicitly typed based on another variable.

```
var json = {foo: 1};
var someTypedVariable = json; // Assignment gives implicit type

someTypedVariable.bar = 1; // Error
someTypedVariable.foo = 1; // Good
```

But is there any way to achieve the same result without assigning?  I know I can do:

```
var someTypedVariable: {foo:number};
```

But what about something like:

```
var json = {foo: 1};
var someTypedVariable: json; // Explicitly typing without assignment
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

**Why am I trying to do this?**
I have some large JSON structures that I would like type checking on.  It's easy to throw the sample data in a ts file, and when I assign that data to a variable, I get type checking on that variable.  I don't want to maintain a class structure for the JSON - I just want to be able to (when the JSON structure changes) copy/paste the new JSON file into my project and see if any of my dependent code breaks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, there is a way! As [the related proposal of type queries](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6606) is already implemented:

```
var json = {foo: 1};
var someTypedVariable : typeof json; // type query, not the string "object"

someTypedVariable.bar = 1; // Error
someTypedVariable.foo = 1; // Good
```

One thing to note is that the `typeof` operator in the context of a type expression is a type query, and doesn't mean the same as `typeof` in a simple expression.

You can try it in the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/).

Comment: Works brilliantly!