# TypeScript - define type based on variable that holds reference to a constructor

Tags: typescript, metaclass, typeof, type-definition

Is it possible to get a type of a variable that holds reference to a constructor/class?

I'm doing:

```
const componentUnderTest = MyComponent;
type TComponentUnderTest = MyComponent;
```

I tried to remove the duplicate `MyComponent` by trying to "extract" the type from `const componentUnderTest`:

```
const componentUnderTest = MyComponent;
type TComponentUnderTest = typeof componentUnderTest; // note my attempt here
```

But I get an error.

But since a related construct works:

```
const componentUnderTest: MyComponent = null;
type TComponentUnderTest = typeof componentUnderTest; // typeof works here
```

thus my Java instincts suggest that it should be something like:

```
type TComponentUnderTest = Type<typeof componentUnderTest>;
```

or

```
type TComponentUnderTest = Constructor<typeof componentUnderTest>;
```

or

```
type TComponentUnderTest = Class<typeof componentUnderTest>;
```

However I'm not sure if such a generic meta-class type exists in TypeScript...

Is it possible to express such a thing?

This is similar to [Declaring type based on variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37577987/declaring-type-based-on-variable) except I want to refer to the constructor/class/type (`const componentUnderTest = MyComponent`).

Comment: Also tried: `type TComponentUnderTest = typeof (typeof componentUnderTest);` but this results in an error.

Comment: Hmm, maybe what I need is a "reverse typeof" operator. Does it exist?

Answer (score 1):

```
type MyConstructor = new (...args: any[]) => MyComponent

let x: MyConstructor
let y = new x()
```